# how do I write a case statement that uses the min function?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to count the number of customers with purchases by month and source only if it was their first purchase. I'm trying to do this using a case statement with the min function but I am getting this error :

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 14:18: CASE WHEN clause must evaluate to a boolean (actual: varchar)
Unique Users by Medium
```

Here is the query I have written:

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT utm as utm , owner, createdon as created
  FROM reelprod.goals
  where 
   createdon > '2019-12-01'
)
SELECT
date_format (From_iso8601_timestamp(nullif(created, '')), '%M') as month,
 json_extract_scalar(utm, '$.medium') AS source,
count (case when min (created) then owner end) as users
FROM dataset
group by json_extract_scalar(utm, '$.medium'), date_format (From_iso8601_timestamp(nullif(created, '')), '%M')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `min(created)` is an aggregate that finds the minimum value for `created` in a set.  The way you're using it doesn't logically make sense--perhaps you mean `min(created) = ???` (where you need to fill in `???` with your desired value)

Comment: as @richyen said, your use of min(created) is incorrect -- the expression is not boolean.  If you use `min(created) = ...` you will have to group by `created` because it's an aggregate function.. I doubt that's what you want.  Instead you may want to do something like `when created = (select min(created) from ...`

Comment: What is the actual issue you are trying to solve? What you have posted is not a issue so much as an improperly  applied solution. You may want to take a look at [ask]. Following that as a template greatly enhances chance of getting a satisfactory answer. Please include sample data - as text NO images, and the expected output of that data.